# Initializing last number in a .data file to either 1 or -1

Tags: java, initialization, storing-data

I have a constructor that takes in data from this .data file:

[image: Data]

***Problem:***

- My code does not initialize the last value in each row to either -1 or 1

The last number is usually 0 or 1 and in this .data file it is the 13th index. If it is 0 I want it stored as a -1, if it is 1 I want it stored as a 1 in the data[][] array.

Here is the specific code:

```
// Copy over data form the .data file
            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                // For each row...
                if (!numbers[j].equals(qMarks)) {
                    // If the values in each row do not equal "?"
                    // Set rows[i] to the values in column[i]
                    if (j == 13){
                        if (numbers[j].equals(positiveHeartCondition)){
                            data[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                        else if (numbers[j].equals(negativeHeartCondition)){
                            data[i][j] = -1;
                        }
                    }
                    data[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[j]);
                    // System.out.println(data[i][j]); //Test code to see
                    // what's printed here
                } else {
                    data[i][j] = 0;
                    // System.out.println(data[i][j]); //Test code to see
                    // what's printed here
                }
            }
```

Here is the code I have for the constructor:

```
public class NeuralNetwork {
/*
 * Setup an 2-d array of doubles to store values from a .data file This will
 * be used in the NeuralNetwork constructor
 */
protected double[][] data;

/*
 * Declare a double[][] array, and randomize the weights of the double array
 * in constructor This will be used in the train(), randomizeWeights(),
 * getWeights() methods
 */
public double[][] weights;

/*
 * We set a double field named eta equal to 0.05. Used in the train() and
 * error() methods
 */
protected double eta = 0.01;

/*
 * These are values for the NeuralNetwork Constructor
 */
private final String comma = ",";
private final String qMarks = "?";
private final String positiveHeartCondition = "1";
private final String negativeHeartCondition = "0";
private Node[] input; // Input Nodes
private Node[] hiddenNodeLayer; // Array of HiddenNode to hold input in each
                                // HiddenNode
private Node outputNode; // Take the input of hiddenNodeLayer

// We initialize a constructor which only takes a parameter int n.
public NeuralNetwork(File f) {

    int noOfNodes = 0;

    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(f);

        int noOfRowsInData = 0;

        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));
        try {
            lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            noOfRowsInData = lnr.getLineNumber();
            lnr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String line = inFile.nextLine();

        String[] numbers = line.split(comma);

        data = new double[noOfRowsInData][numbers.length];

        noOfNodes = numbers.length - 1;

        int i = 0;
        // While there is another line in inFile.
        inFile = new Scanner(f);

        while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
            // Store that line into String line
            line = inFile.nextLine();
            // System.out.println(line);//Test code to see what the file
            // looks like
            // Parition values separated by a comma
            numbers = line.split(comma);
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(columns)); //Test code to
            // see length of each column
            /*
             * code works and prints out row
             */
            /*
             * initialize noOfNodes to length of numbers - 1
             */

            // This will count the number of rows in the .data file

            // System.out.println(data[0].length); //Test code works
            // properly, and prints numbers.length

            // Copy over data form the .data file
            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                // For each row...
                if (!numbers[j].equals(qMarks)) {
                    // If the values in each row do not equal "?"
                    // Set rows[i] to the values in column[i]
                    if (j == 13){
                        if (numbers[j].equals(positiveHeartCondition)){
                            data[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                        else if (numbers[j].equals(negativeHeartCondition)){
                            data[i][j] = -1;
                        }
                    }
                    data[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[j]);
                    // System.out.println(data[i][j]); //Test code to see
                    // what's printed here
                } else {
                    data[i][j] = 0;
                    // System.out.println(data[i][j]); //Test code to see
                    // what's printed here
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

        // System.out.println(data.length); //See what the length of the
        // data double array is. works
        // Test code to print out the 2-d double array and see what is being
        // stored
         for (int k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
         System.out.println("For Row[" + k + "] of file:"); // Works
         for (int j = 0; j < data[k].length; j++) {
         System.out.println("   data[" + k + "][" + j + "] = "
         + data[k][j]); // Works
         }
         }
         }
```

Comment: Run your code in a debugger. Set a breakpoint on the `if (j == 13)` line. When the breakpoint hits, step through the code to see what happens and what the exact values of the variables are, to discover why it's not doing what you think it should be doing.

Comment: Found a workaround right before you made this comment :-) but too many if and else statements :'(

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, but I would prefer not to use so many if and else statements :/

```
for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
                // For each row...
                if (!numbers[j].equals(qMarks)) {
                    // If the values in each row do not equal "?"
                    // Set rows[i] to the values in column[i]
                    if (j != 13){
                        data[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[j]);
                        }
                    else {
                        if (j == 13 && numbers[j].equals(positiveHeartCondition)){
                            data[i][j] = 1;
                        }
                        else if (j == 13 && numbers[j].equals(negativeHeartCondition)){
                            data[i][j] = -1;
                        }
                    }
                    // System.out.println(data[i][j]); //Test code to see
                    // what's printed here
                } else {
                    data[i][j] = 0;
                    // System.out.println(data[i][j]); //Test code to see
                    // what's printed here
                }
            }
```